# Firefox version of: chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have a Chrome extension that listens for updates on a page. The onUpdated method calls the listener after any change made on the page. <strike>If you add or remove a DOM node>, the listener is called.</strike> UPDATE: it seems it's called after loading requests.

I started to port this extension to Firefox and so far I couldn't find a similar functionality. I think I might need to dig into XPCOM.

Could someone point me to the right direction? Does Firefox offer something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this link [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Appendix_F:_Monitoring_DOM_changes?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=XUL%2FSchool_tutorial%2FAppendix_F%3A_Monitoring_DOM_changes)

Comment: Arecyou sure the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` event is triggered when you insert/delete a node ?

Comment: So to be more precise. It's not when I insert or delete any node but for instance, when a modal window is loaded with some remote content, chrome.tabs.onUpdated event is triggered. So actually it depends.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a Chrome extension already, you should definitely look in the [Addon SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/index.html) when you're trying to port it to a Firefox Add-on (this is the "new" way of writing Firefox add-ons, opposed to writing XUL/XPCOM). This SDK provides most of the "standard extension functionality" that you find in other extension platforms.

I'm a bit puzzled about the way of phrasing your question. Your title is crystal-clear: You're looking for the equivalent of [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated). However, in your question's body, you're implying that this event is somehow used to detect when a DOM node is added/removed. This is false.

There is not a single equivalent to [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) in the Add-on SDK:

- Chrome's "status" change:

  - "loading" - [tabs' "open" event](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html#open).
  - "complete" - The [tab's "ready" event](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html#ready_5) (if you want to track a specific tab, see the ["ready" event of a `Tab` instance](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html#ready)).
- Chrome's "url" change:

  - [tabs' "open" event](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html#open).
- Chrome's "pin" state change: *no equivalent*
- Chrome's "favicon" change: *no equivalent*

These events can only be used in the add-on's main.js (equiv. of Chrome's background page). If you want to send a message to a content script, see [this guide](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-port.html).

---

If you're not interested in any of the tab update events (described above), and only in DOM node changes, just stick to content scripts and have almost the same code in your Chrome extension and Firefox add-on. [Chrome's content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) are declared in the manifest file, whereas [Firefox' content scripts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/index.html#content-scripts) are declared in main.js.

Both Chrome and Firefox support [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), which can be used to efficiently get notified of DOM node changes.

Comment: Yeah, I thought chrome.tabs.onUpdated event was triggered on any DOM update because when a modal window is opened it would trigger it.

Comment: What I basically need is to listen for URL changes. Some websites change the whole URL and not just the hash and the events that were supposed to be triggered, aren't. So chrome.tabs.onUpdated did the trick, I'd check the URL after each update to see if it changed.

Comment: @fromvega If you log the `details` object of the `onUpdated` event, you would see that the `"loading"` event caused this change. From your description, it seems that you want to detect navigation changes. In that case, use the [`chrome.webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html) events. Firefox does not have such an API to my knowledge, so you would have to use [PageMod](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html) to detect creation of frames.

Comment: exactly, I want to detect navigation changes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Firefox does support that. It is just that in Firefox extensions can be xul-based, bootstraped or sdk-based and sdk may not support everything you might need for your extension to work.

The following solution applies to both xul-based and bootstraped extensions.

In my bootstrapped extension I use this:

First, define a tabProgressListener. The [`onLocationChange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Listening_to_events_on_all_tabs#onLocationChange) is what you are looking for

```
var tabProgressListener = {
  onLocationChange: function (
      /*nsIDOMXULElement*/ aBrowser,
        /*nsIWebProgress*/ aWebProgress,
        /*nsIRequest*/ aRequest,
        /*nsIURI*/ aLocation) {
        myExtension.handleTabLocationChanged(aBrowser, aLocation);
  },

  onProgressChange: function() {},
  onSecurityChange: function() {},
  onStateChange: function() {},
  onStatusChange: function() {},
  onRefreshAttempted: function(
    /*nsIDOMXULElement*/ aBrowser,
    /*nsIWebProgress*/ webProgress,
    /*nsIURI*/ aRefreshURI,
    /*long*/ aMillis,
    /*boolean*/ aSameURI) {
      // must return true to allow http-meta refreshes
      return true;

  },
  onLinkIconAvailable: function() {}
};
```

and then add tabProgressListener on window load

```
var gBrowser = document.getElementById('content');
gBrowser.addTabsProgressListener(tabProgressListener);
```

Finally, remember to remove the progress listener

```
gBrowser.removeTabsProgressListener(tabProgressListener);
```

Note that although I am not a fan of addon-sdk, it is much easier to write a sdk extension than a bootstraped one.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you need to wait until a tab is ready to have access to the URL. So, using the Add-on SDK, a simplified version of this (just for the active tab) would be:

### main.js

```
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
var tab = tabs.activeTab;
var url = tab.url;
tab.on('ready', function() {
    if (tab.url === url) {
        //user just refreshed the page
        return;
    }
    url = tab.url;
    //The URL is different, let's code…
});
```

See the [docs for the tab module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html) for more info. If you wanted it to work for multiple tabs, you would start with `tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {…});` You would then have to create an array of URLs then check `if (urls[tab.index] === tab.url) …`

Comment: I tried it before but there are times it doesn't catch URL changes. Just an example: if you get on Google, then make a search, then follow to see more results. The URL and content will change a couple of times but this code won't catch it.

Comment: I was having a similar issue with `PageMod`. Try adding an onunload event listener to your content script and see if that makes a difference. You shouldn't have to put anything in the listener's function; simply registering it should do the trick.

Comment: Could you provide me an example?

Comment: Sorry, was on holiday. You put the listener in the content script. I'm using Jquery, so just used [`$( window ).unload(function() {});`](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) If you're not using it, [`window.onunload = function(){};`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onunload) should work too, though I haven't tested it. The only downside to this method is that it prevents users from the benefits of a soft refresh when they press the back button (i.e. the whole webpage has to relaod from scratch).